# Ruby on Rails, how to make a copy of an HTTP request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently, I have a Rails app, where I receive an HTTP Get request and then process it. What I want to do is when I get this request, I want to make a copy of the request but change the URL while keeping everything the same and send the request to my new URL. However, this should be a copy, I would like my Rails app to continue processing the original request.

I know I can use NET:HTTP to make an HTTP request but I am not sure on how I can preserve all of the original request parameters and headers.

Comment: Ah, for several years now, I want to write a tool to clone/redirect production traffic. Never get the time :/

Comment: If you want to perform the requests simultaneously you need to use [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) or some other HTTP lib that supports parallel requests. `NET:HTTP` cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

```
# get request url
url = request.original_url

# parse url into URI object
uri = URI(url)

# replace current host with new host
uri.host = "newhost.com"

# forward request to new host
response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
```

Comment: What else do you need to accomplish this?